# How can I use NARF in PCL libray for Object regconition

Tags: kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I would like use kinect and PCL library to determine the location XYZ of a small object.
I have try HSI threshold but it not really useful, the object bout 1mm*1mm*1mm.

Thanks you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9763/how-can-i-use-narf-in-pcl-libray-for-object-regconition/) by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-04-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you have a look at the NARF section in the [PCL tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials/)?

Also, for such a tiny object, the Kinect's resolution is not high enough (for use with NARF, or anything else - there are simply not enough points on the object). Did you try visualize the Kinect point cloud in RViz, and had a look at it? If a human can't separate the object from the background noise, then forget about automated object recognition.

What other properties does the object have? Does it have a salient color? If yes, you would probably do much better with a high-resolution camera and some color blob detection. You mentioned trying a HSI threshold, why didn't it work?

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks you,

With HSI threshold large object is work well, with small objects sometime it appear and some time it's disappear.

I used to use cvblob library of 2D blob detection, do we have blob detection in PCL library?

---

Originally posted by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) with karma: 121 on 2011-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might also want to give the SURE 3D features a try:

code.google.com/p/sure-3d-features

They have been used for place recognition:

"Place Recognition using Surface Entropy Features"

[www.ais.uni-bonn.de/papers/ICRA_WS_SPME_2012_Fiolka_et_al.pdf](http://www.ais.uni-bonn.de/papers/ICRA_WS_SPME_2012_Fiolka_et_al.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [Sven Behnke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4059/sven-behnke/) with karma: 43 on 2013-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-02-04**:
Thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of that. This looks really useful.